# How to disable auth completely on react-redux-firebase?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-firebase, react-redux-firebase

I'm creating a playground app for the `react-redux-firebase` with React Native. I want to completely disable the auth module because I only need the Firestore.

The docs did not mention this, I think all the examples include the `userProfile` on the config and this is related to Auth if I'm not mistaken.

I'm getting the expected error when using `react-native-firebase`

`Error: You attempted to use firebase.auth but this module could not be found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I've found it

Set `initializeAuth` to `false` on rrf provider props